# Добавление источника данных

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

При добавлении нового источника данных нельзя выбрать "модель EDM". Раньше можно было выбрать между набором данных и моделью EDM, а сейчас нет. Как можно добавить ее в источники данных сейчас? Использую VS 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Visual Studio 2013 исключено расширение для работы с EDM =(
Остается пробовать через ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Comment: Почему? Они отказываются от EF ?